# How to insert an Entry at specific ListView index? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have listview with items in it. I want to insert an entry to the tapped item in listview. I can get the index of the tapped item and how can I use the index to insert an Entry to that particular index.

```
void selected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return; 
        }

        var i = (list.ItemsSource as List<TestReading>).IndexOf(e.SelectedItem as TestReading);                  
        Entry edit = new Entry { Placeholder="Edit here" };


        //comment out if you want to keep selections
        ListView lst = (ListView)sender;
        lst.SelectedItem = null;

    }
```

Comment: just insert a new item in your list's datasource at the selected index

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I showed you how to detect the click on your row in list view.

[How to set focus on Entry inside Listview? Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817680/how-to-set-focus-on-entry-inside-listview-xamarin-forms)

In ViewCell_Tapped use

```
var sl=(StackLayout)sender.View;
```

Then you can programmatically add your entry to it's children. If you cell layout structure is different than I showed in the answer cast View to appropriate type. You also can give your stacklayout a name and use FindByName